# a schema cannot contain two global components with the same name

Tags: java, xml, spring

I get this error

```
Referenced file contains errors (project-aware://go-ontology/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."   gorules-ontology-beans.xml  /go-ontology/src/main/resources line 1  XML Problem
```

When I check "More details", it gives me the following:

```
The errors below were detected when validating the file "spring-beans-3.1.xsd" via the file "gorules-ontology-beans.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "spring-beans-3.1.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when spring-beans-3.1.xsd is validated in the context of gorules-ontology-beans.xml.


    sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans,identifiedType'.
```

gorules-ontology-beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd
    ">

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="pl.polsl.lstypka.gorules.ontology.reporitory" />

</beans>
```

I'm not so good in java, I found few solutions but it didnt work. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens when I run this validation using Saxon (the output is produced using the command line -t option):

```
Saxon-EE 9.7.0.7J from Saxonica
Java version 1.6.0_27
Using license serial number V000006
Schema checking successful. Time: 0ms. Memory: 3Mb.
Using parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Processing file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml
URIResolver.resolve href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" base="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml"
Loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
Finished loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
URIResolver.resolve href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" base="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml"
Loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
Warning at xsd:import on line 11 column 153 of spring-context-3.0.xsd:
  The schema document at http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd is
  not being read because schema components for this namespace are already available. To
  force the schema document to be read, set --multipleSchemaImports:on
URIResolver.resolve href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd" base="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
Loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
Finished loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
Finished loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
URIResolver.resolve href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd" base="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xml"
Loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd
URIResolver.resolve href="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.0.xsd" base="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd"
Loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.0.xsd
Warning at xsd:import on line 11 column 87 of spring-repository-1.0.xsd:
  The schema document at http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd is
  not being read because schema components for this namespace are already available. To
  force the schema document to be read, set --multipleSchemaImports:on
Finished loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.0.xsd
Finished loading schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd
Validation time: 368ms. Memory: 15Mb.
Validation successful
```

What those warnings are saying is that somewhere in your hierarchy of schema documents there are two references to schemas with the same namespace (it might or might not be the same actual schema document that's referenced, and the reference might or might not be the same actual URL). Saxon has made a guess that the second reference can be ignored because it's probably the same schema document, and on this occasion it seems that Saxon has guessed correctly, because a different processor (yours) took a different decision, followed both references, and ended up with multiple definitions of the same component as a result.